# How to make recursive function that counts the number of occurences in a string in python

Tags: python

I tried this to count the number of occurences of the target in a string in a recursive way, but I don't think where len(target) > 1 is a recursive way. I can't really think of other way to do this in a recursive way. I am doing this without using any string methods except indexing and slicing. Please give some help.

target can be a single character or a substring.

For example, if s = 'aaaaabb' and target = 'aa', i want the output to be 4.

```
def count(s, target):
    if s == '':
        return 0
    if len(target) > len(s):
        return 0

    if len(target) <= 1:
        if s[0] == target:
            return 1 + count(s[1:], target)
        else:
            return 0 + count(s[1:], target)

    if len(target) > 1:
        count = 0
        for x in range(len(s) - len(target) + 1):
            if s[x:x+len(target)] == target:
                count += 1
        return count
```

Comment: Why don’t you just use a for loop?

Comment: You have reassigned `count` inside `def count` which breaks the ability to use the `count` function recursively from within.

Comment: "target" can be a single character and a substring

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def count_substring(s, target):
    if not s:
        return 0
    return (s[:len(target)] == target) + count_substring(s[1:], target)

print(count_substring('aaaaabb', 'aa')) # 4
```

The idea is that at each recursion, the function only cares about the left-most substring, to compare with `target`. You can think of it as a slight modification of your `len(target) <= 1` case.

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you please explain what 'if not s:' does in this function?

Comment: @BAbabo It is a short-hand notation (or slight abuse) of `if s == ''`. A string is "falsy" if and only if it is empty. So `not s` is equivalent to `not bool(s)` which is equivalent to `not (s != '')`, which is the same as `s == ''`.